# Multiple List Individual append

Tags: python, list, append

Anyone know if there is a way to do something like this?:

```
def function(a, b, z):
    code
    return x, y, z

X, Y, Z = [] for i in range(3)
for a in range(rows):
    for b in range(cols):
         X.append(), Y.append(), Z.append() = function(a, b, z)
```

so that on each iteration each corresponding value goes to its proper list

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; you have to unpack the return value first, then pass each value to the appropriate function.

```
v1, v2, v3 = function(a, b, z)
X.append(v1)
Y.append(v2)
Z.append(v3)
```

By the way, `X, Y, Z = [] for i in range(3)` isn't valid syntax. Just write

```
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
```

You might consider a list (or dict) of lists instead of separate names `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.

```
results = [[], [], []]
for a in range(rows):
    for b in range(cols):
        vs = function(a, b, z)
        for lst, v in zip(results, vs):
            lst.append(v)
```

but for only 3 lists, I don't think this gains you much.

Comment: Oh thanks! in the end what i liked the most was:  [lst.append(v) for lst, v in zip(results, vs)] right afther vs = ...,  It filled up every list perfectly on each iteration

Comment: Do not use a list comprehension if you don't actually want a list of `None`s. Just use a regular for loop.

Comment: Oddly enough, although the list comprehension did return a list of None's, the values of each list was updated individually and I could plot them without issues.

Comment: Yes, `lst.append` is still called, and it returns `None` in addition to its side effect of updating the list referenced by `lst`.